# How to extract 3 substrings with Regex (Google flavor)?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to extract three substrings, separated by a simple comma. Regex flavor I need to work with is Google (inside their DataStudio product) and I am using Regex101 to test out my expressions.

Here is the scenario:

**Example string I need to parse**:

```
US, Luxor, someThirdString
```

**Expression(s) I am trying**:

```
"(.*?),"
```

not good, captures "**US,**" (*the "," as well*);

```
",(.*?),"
```

not good, captures "**, Luxor,**" (*the two "," as well*);

I tried using positive look-aheads but that one got me nowhere unfortunately. Expected output is three separate fields:

- "US"
- "Luxor"
- "someThirdString"

I don't need a single complex regex to capture substrings into another concatenated string but rather 3 separate substrings, so I am ok with three steps (three operations).

Comment: Your match is in the capturing group.

Comment: Will there ever be spaces in the substrings between the commas? What about any special characters?

Comment: @Nick Reed: we cant know; this will be user input, free text field.

Comment: @AlexStarbuck That runs the issue of the user including commas in their input - if they do that, you're not going to be able to parse it with regex alone. For example, "foo, bar, hello, world"

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure they are always three, you can use:

```
(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)
```

This will capture one match, but 3 groups. You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/iHoL9K/2)

You can also use:

```
\W*(\w+)
```

This will capture 3 matches and the string will be one group for each match. This can be useful if you are not sure on the number of matching groups. You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/iHoL9K/1).

Update:

1. `^(\w+)` - [here](https://regex101.com/r/iHoL9K/4).
2. `,\s*(\w+)\s*,` - [here](https://regex101.com/r/iHoL9K/5).
3. `^(\w+)` - [here](https://regex101.com/r/iHoL9K/3).

Comment: I see that this works nicely :), however, still not solving the problem. Since I do not have the option of splitting the captured substring of three groups, I need three separate expressions: one to capture first group, second to start looking from the SECOND comma, capturing second group and finally, third expression to start after the third comma. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After seeing a comment on a previous answer, if you're willing to do three separate regexes for the first, second, and third substrings, these three should solve your problem:

```regex
^(.*?),.*$        first substring to first comma
^.*, (.*?),.*$    second substring from first comma to second comma, assuming a space after the first comma
^.*,.*, (.*)$     third substring from second comma to end, assuming a space after second comma
```

[Try](https://regex101.com/r/OYuluw/3) [them](https://regex101.com/r/OYuluw/4) [here!](https://regex101.com/r/OYuluw/5)

Comment: Nick, thanks! I see how these should work, but in the meantime I realized that there are so many problems with Regex route that I think we have to do it in a completely different way (what if user inputs a regex token, illegal chars, etc.). What's the proper way to remove questions from SO? Thanks once again for your effort!

Comment: @AlexStarbuck Not a problem, glad I could clarify. The delete button should be below the original question. Good luck with your code!